# Google Apps Script Error: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to bring all my website data into a google sheet to review something. This is the code that I have written:

```
function callNumbers() {
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("my website API link");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  
 var companies = response.getContent();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 for (var i = -1; i < companies.data.length; i++) {
    Logger.log('Domain: ' + companies.data[i]["exid"]);
        Logger.log('Name: ' + companies.data[i]["name"]);
    sheet.appendRow([companies.data[i]["exid"], companies.data[i]["name"]]);
 
}
```

The error I get is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 8, file "Code")

Can anyone please help me fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you console logged the response to see what data are you working with? Can you share more information?

Answer (score 0):

I don't work much with apps-script but according to the docs:

getContent()
Gets the raw binary content of an HTTP response.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getContent()

```
// The code below logs the value of the first byte of the Google home page.
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/");
Logger.log(response.getContent()[0]);
Return
Byte[] — the content as a raw binary array
```

So try without the .data